# trying to get left right arrows to stick on edges of large image.

Tags: html, css

I have a image the scales to the screen size. I'm trying to get a left, right and close buttons to stay on the image but I can only get them to stay on the edges of the screen.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kvE96/11/)

```
#full_image ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  width:100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
 }
#full_image li{
  display:block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#full_image li a {display:block}
#full_image ul li img{ margin:0 auto; max-width:100%}

#full_image .full_close{
  background-color: red;
  top: 10px;     
  cursor: pointer;    
  height: 29px;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;    
  width: 29px;
  z-index: 999;
  right: 10px;
 }
#full_image .next_big{
  background-color: red;
  top: 50%;     
  cursor: pointer;    
  height: 29px;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;    
  width: 29px;
  z-index: 999;
  right: 0px;
}

#full_image .prev_big{
  background-color: red;
  top: 50%;     
  cursor: pointer;    
  height: 29px;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;    
  width: 29px;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 0px;
  color: #222;
   }


<div id="full_image"> 
  <ul><li><a href="#"> <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01636/saint-tropez-beach_1636818c.jpg" alt="" /></a></li> </ul>    
    <a href="#" class="full_close"></a>
    <a href="#" class="button next_big"></a>
    <a href="#" class="button prev_big"></a>

   </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use display:block on the parent containers they will stretch the full width. You will have to either use display:inline-block or float the element.

If you have to support older browsers this trick may work:

```
#full_image{
     display:inline-block;
     *display:inline;/* For IE7*/
     *zoom:1/* For IE7*/
     text-align:left;
    }
```

You will have to remove the display block on the li a.

You have to also add position relative to the #full_image div to make sure the absolutely positioned items are positioned inside that div rather than the screen.

Here is an updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kvE96/15/

Answer (score 0):

Format your container with `display:inline-block` (so that it is only as wide as the image actually), and `position:relative` to make it the point of reference for the absolute positioning of children.

See http://jsfiddle.net/kvE96/11/

Comment: thank you a million but the image no longer scales with you make the window smaller